# How to only run a function that generates a "back to top" button based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, media-queries

I have a back-to-top button which appears when users scroll down on the website, however, I would like it if this button only appeared depending on screen size.

As somebody new to javascript, I cannot figure out how to add this in, other than that I am assuming it should be a part of the "if" argument.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="button-top" title="Go to top">Top</button>
```

CSS code:

```
        #button-top {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    border: none; 
    outline: none;
    background-color: #d46900;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

#button-top:hover {
    color: #1c1c1c;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

JS code:

```
/* BACK TO TOP BUTTON*/
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("button-top").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("button-top").style.display = "none";
    }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```

Comment: For clarification, I added the CSS code that goes with the JS code. Mediaqueries aren't an option as the JS code overrides them since the button has the "display: none;" by default already.

Answer (score 1):

You should use media queries to show or hide your button depending on the screen size:

```css
/* Hide the button if the width is less than 500px */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #button-top {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button-top">Back to top</button>
```

You can run the snippet above and resize your browser, once the width is below 500px, the button will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want.
If you want your button-top button to appear on bigger screen like desktop and disappear on smaller screen like tablets or mobile you can do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #button-top {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

but if you want your button-top button to appear after scrolling and disappear after scrolling back to top you can do something like this:

css:

```
#button-top.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("#button-top").addClass("show");
    } else {
        $("#button-top").removeClass("show");
    }
});
```